# Apache Rewrite a-b.domain.com to domain.com/a/b?

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, subdomain, subdirectory

Trying to do a rewrite so that someone going to url like:

a-b.domain.com actually views domain.com/a/b

possible w/ just a rewrite?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible. You can refer below code which I prepared long back.

```
RewriteEngine On                                                            -- This will enable rewrite module 
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*).abc\.domain\.com/([^/]*) [NC] -- This will check Hostname & URI where first (.*) = %1 & second (.*) = %2 variable as we needed dynamic variables so we greped it.
RewriteCond %1<->%2 !^(.*)<->\1$ [NC]                                        -- This will check if condition %1 is not equal to %2 than proceed to rewrite to the rule mentioned below.
RewriteRule ^(.*)      http://domain.com:9090/%1$1 [QSA,P]                   --  This will append %1 in URL so with help of proxy settings it will grab the content from tomcat @ port 9090 with directory name %1 and keep the query string as it is with help of "QSA" string.
RewriteCond %1<->%2 ^(.*)<->\1$ [NC]                                        -- This will check if condition %1 is equal to %2 than proceed to rewrite to the rule mentioned below.
RewriteRule ^(.*)      http://domain.com:9090$1 [QSA,P]                         --  This will not append %1 in URL so with help of proxy settings it will grab the content from tomcat @ port 9090 with directory name %1 and keep the query string as it is with help of "QSA" string.
```